# Use mysql having access to the server by ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh, centos, mariadb

I must have tried every answer in stackoverflow for this problem, nothing works. Anyway:

I installed successfully mariadb 10 on centos 6.5, now I was trying to create database and all those things when I stumbled upon: `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'`. I seem to try logging in anonymously but I am really trying as root.

I logged in typing:

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: [none]
```

it entered and after I tried using mysql database:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

I tried this locally by opening a tunnel in ssh as well

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 dev@machine.com
```

didn't work, also tried in bash...nothing works. Any other advice?

Comment: Did it say `(using password: NO)` or ...YES ?  `localhost` is socket, not port 3306.

Comment: Either way I am able to login with or without password using root. The thing is that afterwords the user is recognized as anonimous.
About the socket, I was able to use the socket, but again logging in gave me access denied when accessing any database...